# Topology : Study on Separation Properties

Tags: gn.general-topology

I want an example of a completely regular space which is not a normal space. I have tried a lot but am unable to construct any example

Comment: http://topology.jdabbs.com for queries of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you are looking for is probably  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niemytzki_plane